# how can i display specific part of webview in android

Tags: android, webview, android-websettings

After going through many post i still not able to resolve the way of showing part of webview in my Application, What exactly i want is to display a specific portion of webpage present inside HTML body. Do suggest some useful solution to resolve the problem

Comment: Does this portion have a tag?

Comment: no it dosen't have any tag or id...its a small table inside that page